# Reallocate space using parted (no gui )

Tags: linux, partitioning, raid, ubuntu-server, parted

I'm running a Ubuntu server 14.04.3 LTS.

The partitioning has been created automatically and now I have a problem with root directory space. There is a raid `/dev/md3` with almost 2 TB free and a `/dev/root` mounted on `/` with 20 gb of which 1.2 gb free.

This is my configuration:

```
# fdisk -l

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sda'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.
Disk /dev/sda: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes
255 testine, 63 settori/tracce, 243201 cilindri, totale 3907029168 settori
Unità = settori di 1 * 512 = 512 byte
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Identificativo disco: 0x00000000

Dispositivo Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1               1  3907029167  1953514583+  ee  GPT

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sdb'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.
Disk /dev/sdb: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes
255 testine, 63 settori/tracce, 243201 cilindri, totale 3907029168 settori
Unità = settori di 1 * 512 = 512 byte
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Identificativo disco: 0x00000000

Dispositivo Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1               1  3907029167  1953514583+  ee  GPT

Disk /dev/md3: 1978.9 GB, 1978886193152 bytes
2 testine, 4 settori/tracce, 483126512 cilindri, totale 3865012096 settori
Unità = settori di 1 * 512 = 512 byte
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Identificativo disco: 0x00000000

Il disco /dev/md3 non contiene una tabella delle partizioni valida

Disk /dev/md2: 21.0 GB, 20970405888 bytes
2 testine, 4 settori/tracce, 5119728 cilindri, totale 40957824 settori
Unità = settori di 1 * 512 = 512 byte
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Identificativo disco: 0x00000000

Il disco /dev/md2 non contiene una tabella delle partizioni valida


# df -h
File system     Dim. Usati Dispon. Uso% Montato su
/dev/root        20G   17G    1,2G  94% /
devtmpfs        7,9G  4,0K    7,9G   1% /dev
none            4,0K     0    4,0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none            1,6G  792K    1,6G   1% /run
none            5,0M     0    5,0M   0% /run/lock
none            7,9G  4,0K    7,9G   1% /run/shm
none            100M     0    100M   0% /run/user
/dev/md3        1,8T  295M    1,7T   1% /home
```

So basically what I need to do is using the `/dev/md3` for `/dev/root` in order to use all the space available!

Please help me because I never used parted without gui and I don't want to make a mess. Obviously I don't want to lose all the data in `/dev/root` (while I don't care about `/dev/md3`).

I don't know if I was on the right way, but I thought I could just change the mount point of `/dev/md3` . I umounted it and mounted on `/` but with no luck. 
Here is my fstab:

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/md2        /       ext4    errors=remount-    ro,relatime,usrjquota=quota.user,grpjquota=quota.group,jqfmt=vfsv0       0           1
/dev/md3        /home   ext4    defaults,relatime       1       2
/dev/sda4       swap    swap    defaults        0       0
/dev/sdb4       swap    swap    defaults        0       0
proc            /proc   proc    defaults                0       0
sysfs           /sys    sysfs   defaults                0       0
devtmpfs        /dev    devtmpfs        rw      0       0
```

Can I just change the mount point to `/` and reboot the server to make it working ? I mean to have all the space of `/dev/md3` on `/` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the problem was related to ISPConfig I asked directly on the forum and they linked me this guide to accomplish my task: 
https://www.howtoforge.com/use_mount_bind_to_move_the_website_and_email_directory_of_a_ispconfig_server_to_a_new_location

Everything went fine and the server is working good again.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to change mount points, you don't have to use parted.
As you note, you can edit fstab to manipulate your fixed mount point.

But, changing the root partition on Linux is more than moving the root mount point. You need to take care and let many of the OS parts know where did you moved the OS to.
Unless you want to reinstall a fresh OS on the extra storage, I recommend not moving the root mount point.
You can mount the extra storage under another "sub-path" on the file system, and use it transparently to it being on another physical media.

A good option is to mount the extra storage as the /home directory. See [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving). Note, that if you have existing users on your current /home, you better first copy the current data to the new location. It is all in the linked guide.

After mounting the extra storage to another path on file system, you can move non OS data to the new space to make more space available on the OS partition.

Comment: I tried changing the /etc/fstab line of /dev/md3 , mounting it on /var but of course all the data in /var was lost and I couldn't reach any of the websites on it. So do you think that if I find a way to copy the content of /var , change the fstab in order to have /dev/md3 on /var and then copy again the content of the 'old' var, will do the trick ?
Anyway did you notice that fstab and df -h output a different file system for directory / ? df -h gives /dev/root , while in fstab there is no /dev/root but /dev/md2 mounted on /. How can it be possible?

Comment: @koo27 you can first mount /dev/md3 to some temporary, neutral, directory and copy the current data from the desired mount point. And only then change mount points.

Comment: Looking again on your outputs, it doesn't look like the default Ubuntu server installation. Are you sure it is Ubuntu 14.04 and not another (Redhat?) distribution? If it is an Ubuntu, had you customized it in the past? How?

Comment: the intsallation was made on soyoustart's ovh server platform. The s.o. is : Ubuntu Server 14.04 "Trusty Tahr" LTS (64bits) and I installed ISPConfig following the 'perfect guide' for ubuntu server 14.04 . nothing else

Comment: what about this: "you can first mount /dev/md3 to some temporary, neutral, directory and copy the current data from the desired mount point. And only then change mount points." Do I have to move back the data from the temporary directory to the new one ?

Comment: Only the mount point is temporary. E.g. If you want to change /var. First mount the new partition to, say, /newPartition and reboot. Then change fstab again but, before the next boot, copy /var to /newPartition. Finally, after another reboot you'll have the new /var with the old data.

Comment: Again, since you can't boot from a third device to do those changes (can you?). I would recommend mounting the new storage to some other alternate location that the system does not currently depend on. Maybe you can use soft links or directory mounts to achieve your goal in another way.

Comment: Ok so taking as reference your penultimate comment, I'll make a realistic example and can you please tell me if I'm right:
According to my fstab I have /var inside / and not in another partition, but I want to give the space of /dev/md3 to /var, so what I'm gonna do is:
1. unmount /dev/md3 and mount it in a new directory, let's say /newPartition
2. copy/move /var content to /newPartition
3. edit fstab in order to have /dev/md3 mounted on /var
4. reboot (I'd like to avoid too many reboot cuz I'm running several sites, so I'll provide a mount -a when needed)
5. done.
Am I right ?

Comment: I'm missing something because after point 3. I will have nothing in /var (because I moved the content in /newPartition ).

Comment: On a stand alone physical machine I would say you can boot from a third part media for the first steps. In this way, /var will not be used when you move the files. But, since in your virtual case /var will be in use, you can't delete essential files. This is one of the reasons I've recommended taking another approach for system critical locations.